# Can't connect to database from file

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I try to connect through: Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient), but I recieve error:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following
>   information:  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a
>   Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
>   properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
>   enabled.)

So, i click Connect to Database in Server Explorer

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9SVttQn.png]

This window show up. In which i choose: Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) and then browse my .mdf database file.

[image]

Clicking ok gives error mentioned before:

[image]

Server is running, I use windows authentication in database.
Any sugestions?

Comment: From the error message, sounds like configuration issue. You can confirm that
1. You have SQL Server Express and not sql server
2. The mdf is a sql server express database and not from another version of sql server

Comment: 1. I have SQL Server 2008 R2 2. mdf is from same version.

Comment: Is F: a local or mapped network drive?

Comment: Local, everything is local.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2 is _NOT_ express. Just attach the DB in sql server management studio and then do a normal connection to the database

Comment: Actually Im doing it this way... But I wanted to try this option.

Comment: It's fine to do it that way... you'll just have to install sql server express. You may even be able to attach the same MDF file, but I'm not sure on that part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need the SQL Server Express LocalDB add-on, you can get it from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) in both x86 & amd64 versions.

Comment: your solution solved my problem. I installed x64 for my 64 bit machine.

Comment: Check which version you need, Installed that version and still had errors. Ended up needing to install Sql Express 2014 from here to fix my issue - https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Comment: For anyone still looking into this issue, the links have updated for the LocalDB add-on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Ensuring that the LocalDB package was installed on my VM solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same issue when I deployed my software on test machine.
Solution:

1. Check the SQL server version using which the .mdf was build.
   If you don't know execute command `SELECT @@VERSION`.
2. Install correct version of SqlLocalDB.msi from following link.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=42299.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **SQL Server Authentication**. Make sure that your **SQL service** is running or not. 
I think this will help you.