# Error 56. Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am in an Advanced Web Development course at my university.  This semester, they began using VS Community 2015 as the IDE (As opposed to 2013 professional) for out of lab exercises.  In our labs, we use 2015 Professional.

**EDIT.**  Just used my roommates Professional 2013, and it still causes the issue.

Nearly everyone in our course cannot do the command 'update-database -verbose' from any computer that is not on our campus, and the professor nor any students know how to fix it.  There are about 3 student's who have it working, but they said it has always worked.

What setting or what download are we missing?  I would really love to be able to work on all my database related courses while not on campus.  Here is the full error set

```
Target database is: 'StudentCourseDb' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified module could not be found

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:126,State:0,Class:20
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)
```

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877770/cant-connect-to-database-from-file

Comment: @LesH Sadly no :(  It said that my machine has a newer version already.

Answer (score 0):

> from any computer that is not on our campus

I don't work with LocalDb..., but a network-related problem seems more than likely, based upon what I just quoted.

I am fairly certain you need to discover what port SQL Server is listening upon. Run SQL Server Configuration Manager (if SSCM is applicable to/installed with LocalDb) | SQL Server Network Configuration | Protocols for SQLEXPRESS | IP Addresses | and see whether TCP Port has an entry. Alternatively, the error log that was active when SQL Server started up will report what IP Address:Port it is listening upon.

If there is no Port entry in SSCM, SQL Server is dynamically choosing a port to listen upon at startup, and the SQL Browser service would need to use UDP traffic to broadcast SQL Server's existence and the dynamic port SQL Server chose.

All that said, your campus' IT staff is likely to block ports in their firewall, even when you connect to campus via a VPN. In other words, I assume your campus' IT staff does not what your school's SQL Servers broadcasting their existence off-campus. However, if you can reveal to your campus IT staff what static (as opposed to dynamic) port SQL Server will be listening upon (using SSCM), they might be willing to open that specific port on their VPN's firewall (I am assuming a VPN is used). But I would not be surprised to discover IT Staff refusing to open a static port for your LocalDb SQL Server, because it is not a good security practice to broadcast SQL Server's existence outside of where it needs to be used (e.g. on campus). If you want to test SQL Server's static port off-campus, before contacting IT, there are various ways to test what port is open, with telnet being one of the oldest methods around.