# Can't add a new connection to my data source

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Can somebody tell me why i can't connect with any .mdf file?
I get this kind a error for each file.

[image]

Comment: See if this helps, [Can't connect to database from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877770/cant-connect-to-database-from-file)

Comment: Does your app have permissions to access the file? I notice it's on the root of the D:\ drive.

Comment: how can i check that ?

Comment: Ty Vyas, it help...the problem was in sql server version...